# how to share a xib file with multiple objective c class

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, ios4, uiviewcontroller

I am new in ios development, so i don't know this question is correct or not.
I want to create a uibutton from a separate  uiview class in view based application template.
if anybody know ,please clear my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty easy to do. This code snippet should help;

```
    NSArray* nibRollViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TiltData" owner:self options:nil];
    myRollDataView = [nibRollViews lastObject]; // TODO, look it up by name, don't assume last

    [myRollDataView setFrame:CGRectMake(rollDataViewFPO.frame.origin.x, 
                                    rollDataViewFPO.frame.origin.y, 
                                    myRollDataView.frame.size.width, 
                                    myRollDataView.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:myRollDataView];
    [myRollDataView initWithType:RollType];
```

There are a few things to note. I have a rollDataViewFPO (FPO means "for position only") in my xib. I use the FPO frame for positioning the object I just loaded. This way I can position it my xib, not my code.

Also note that I call my own initWithType method. My TiltData objects can be used to show Roll or Pitch data, and I need to tell them what type they are.

Answer (score 0):

Add a newFile ObjectiveC class make it as SubClass of UIView(assume name here: SubView).

if you doesn't want to use the view of UIViewController Class then just select the view in xib

of UiViewController and change the class name to SubView in inspector window.put the UIButton

in that view and do anything what you want.If you want Separate View then simply drag and

drop UIView from menu bar and connect that as an outlet to your ViewController Class and

change name of UIView class to SubView.